# Calling PHP unlink() after move_uploaded_file() on moved file fails

Tags: php, imagick

I am sending files uploaded to my server to **Amazon S3**. To do this, I:

- Use `move_uploaded_file()` to send file to a temp-uploads folder.
- I use the S3 SDK to upload the file as an object to S3.
- I use `unlink()` to delete the file.
- `unlink()` fails with *Resource temporarily unavailable*

Windows Server running PHP/Apache.

I can unlink later after the script is done running. Calling the `unlink()` command outside of the script deletes the file from the server immediately. I was trying to figure out how to maybe release the file from `move_uploaded_file()`, but can't find anything after searching for a while.

I do use `$thumb1 = new Imagick($filetothumbnail);` and create a thumbnail. But I then call

```
$thumb1->clear();
$thumb1->destroy();
```

Maybe Imagick still has the file open? However, I have tested this with an excel file which does not make a thumbnail, and the file still fails to delete from the server.

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
  $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
  $tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

  $newname = time().'_'.$j['id'].'_'.$name;
  $thumbname = 'tn_'.time().'_'.$j['id'].'_'.$name;
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "temp-uploads/".$newname);

  //Now, generate thumbnail for the file:
  $filetothumbnail = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/temp-uploads/'.$newname;
  $thumbnails = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/temp-uploads/thumbs/';

  //Send to AWS Bucket
  $s3_filepath = 'project-assets/'.$newname;
  upload_s3_file($s3_filepath, "temp-uploads/".$newname);

  $filepath = s3url.$s3_filepath;

  if($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'png' || $ext == 'gif'){

  $thumb1 = new Imagick($filetothumbnail);
  $compression_type = Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG; 

  $thumb1->setImageCompression($compression_type); 
  $thumb1->setImageCompressionQuality(40);
  $thumb1->thumbnailImage(500, 0);
  $thumb1->setImageFormat('jpg');
  $thumb1->writeimage($thumbnails.$thumbname);
  $thumb1->clear();
  $thumb1->destroy();

  //If thumbnail is there. Only for certain file types.
  $s3_thumbpath = 'project-thumbnails/'.$thumbname;
  upload_s3_file($s3_thumbpath, "temp-uploads/thumbs/".$thumbname);

  unlink("temp-uploads/thumbs/".$thumbname); //Delete Thumbnail.

  $thumbpath = s3url.$s3_thumbpath;

  } else {
  $thumbpath = 0;
  }


  unlink("temp-uploads/".$newname); //Delete Uploaded File.
}
```

The upload to S3 function is:

```
$s3Client = new S3Client([
  'version'     => 'latest',
  'region'      => 'us-east-2',
  'credentials' => [
     'key'    => s3key,
     'secret' => s3secret,
   ],
]);

$result = $s3Client->putObject([
  'Bucket' => 'bucketname',
  'Key' => $filename,
  'SourceFile' => $filepath,
]);
```

Comment: I suspect it's the S3 SDK that's locking the file, nothing to do with move_uploaded_file.

Comment: Are you trying to delete the temp file that is created?

Comment: Please show your full code

Comment: @markt Full code added. Is the S3 perhaps not yet finished? I thought that the upload to S3 wouldn't execute further code until it was finished. Maybe just adding a delay or wait?

Comment: I will try with the full path. $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/temp-uploads/thumbs/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post helped solve this for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41537354/1766536

Specifically, I had to use `fopen`/`fclose` and upload using `Body` instead of `SourceFile`

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the docs suggests that the upload is asynchronous:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_promises.html

And you should probably use a promise to create a callback in which you can unlink your file. There are plenty of code examples in the link.

Comment: This will likely be the correct answer. I was wondering about that. I started to read about using promises within and got sidetracked. Thank you so much.

Comment: This didn't solve the locked file. Changing to `Body` instead of `SourceFile` and properly opening/closing the file let me `unlink()` the file after upload.